# Python docstring with vim pythoncomplete is not displaying newlines for my own class functions

Tags: python, vim, autocomplete, docstring

I am getting some unexpected results when trying to use [Python Omni Completion](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1542) on my own class functions. The docstring for the functions are not getting formatted correctly with line breaks as shown in the picture below:

[image: Unexpected result]

When I am importing modules from the standard python library I get the result I would expect:

[image: Expected result]

According to the python [docstring conventions](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/) a newline in the source file should be interpreted as a newline. Does anyone know what's going on here and perhaps how to solve the issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Edit: I wrote an autocompletion, which should is **much better** than pythoncomplete: https://github.com/davidhalter/jedi-vim

---

The `Python Omni Completion` of vim is pretty stupid. It's a simple script which parses the current file and `imports` all the others. This is pretty dangerous and shouldn't be done. However it works not that bad (but also not good at all).

So really the difference between your two scenarios is, that the standard libraries are being imported. So are your files, but not the current file. If you used a second module named `test2` and used:

```
import test
test.mydoc.prettyStr
```

It should work.

Your current file is being parsed. The parser is simple and not really good. The dostring parser is especially strange because of this line (line number ~290):

```
docstr = docstr.replace('\n', ' ')
```

You can modify it - just change this file:
`/usr/share/vim/vim73/autoload/pythoncomplete.vim` Maybe it's in a different directory.

Currently I'm in the process of writing a better autocompletion for python/vi (this is also the reason why I know this). But that's still quite some work. I hope I'll be ready with a Beta in a month. I try to keep you posted.

Comment: That explains quite a few things! Thank you.